How to change the value to formatted text?
I have a group of dates that are in the format: mm/dd/yyyy. I need them to be in the format: yyyy-mm-dd.
I formatted the cells to match the proper order, however the values of the cells do not change, only how they are displayed.
I am wondering how to make the actual value follow this formatting as well.

Check that the cells contains really date type or text which content is  a string of a date.

Why would you want the Value of the cell to change? Is the problem, perhaps, that the Value is incorrect? If so, it is a data entry problem and should be addressed at that level.

You state, "I formatted the cells to match the proper order, however the values of the cells do not change, only how they are displayed."
That is good news, because a date-time should not be stored in the spreadsheet as mm/dd/yyyy nor as yyyy-mm-dd, but instead as a floating-point number.

In the example above, the same value is displayed in columns A, B, and C, but using different format strings.
Look at the last row. Each day is an integer, the number of days after 30 Dec 1899. The fractional part is the time portion, with one second being 1/(60 sec/min x 60 min/hr x 24 hr/day) = 1/86,400 sec/day = 1.157407... x 10-5. So one second is shown as 0.000011574..., which is stored internally as that F.P. number.
That allows a spreadsheet to calculate differences between dates (e.g., How many days from today until school holiday? How many days since Id Mar AUC DCCX, until today?).
Unless the date/time is specifically stored in a column formatted as literal text, then a spreadsheet can perform calculations on date-time, and can display that date-time any way you wish -- Gregorian calendar, Julian day, Chinese calendar, הַלּוּחַ הָעִבְרִי, ٱلتَّقْوِيم ٱلْهِجْرِيّ, etc.
So don't change the internal storage of a date-time, just format the cells to display it correctly.

If you need a text instead of date you can use a formula:
=TEXT(date,"yyyy-mm-dd")

where date is a reference to a cell containing date.

To change how the date will display without changing the actual value in Excel, select the dates then
Go to Home Tab > Number Group > click on down arrow to open the Format Cells window > click on Custom > type yyyy-mm-dd.



